# How to ignore the punctuation c#

Tags: c#

I want to ignore the punctuation.So, I'm trying to make a program that counts all the appearences of every word in my text but without taking in consideration the punctuation marks.
So my program is:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "This my world. World, world,THIS WORLD ! Is this - the world .";
        IDictionary<string, int> wordsCount =
         new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
        text=text.ToLower();
        text = text.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z\text]", "X");
        string[] words = text.Split(' ',',','-','!','.');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            int count = 1;
            if (wordsCount.ContainsKey(word))
                count = wordsCount[word] + 1;
            wordsCount[word] = count;
        }

        var items = from pair in wordsCount
                    orderby pair.Value ascending
                    select pair;

        foreach (var p in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", p.Key, p.Value);
        }

    }
```

The output is:

```
is->1
my->1
the->1
this->3
world->5
(here is nothing) -> 8
```

How can I remove the punctuation here?

Comment: Use `text.Split(new [] {" ", ",", "-", "!", "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` to exclude the empty entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try specifying `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] words = text.Split(" ,-!.".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Note that instead of manually creating a `char[]` with all the punctuation characters, you may create a `string` and call `ToCharArray()` to get the array of characters.

I find it easier to read and to modify later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
   string[] words = text.Split(new char[]{' ',',','-','!','.'}, StringSplitOPtions.RemoveEmptyItems);
```

Comment: That one doesn't compile.  You need the `new char[] {...}` version.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple - first step is to remove undesired punctuation with function `Replace` and then continue with splitting as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

... you can go with the making people cry version ...

```
"This my world. World, world,THIS WORLD ! Is this - the world ."
    .ToLower()
    .Split(" ,-!.".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(i=>new{Word=i.Key, Count = i.Count()})
    .OrderBy(k => k.Count)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

.. output

```
{ Word = my, Count = 1 }
{ Word = is, Count = 1 }
{ Word = the, Count = 1 }
{ Word = this, Count = 3 }
{ Word = world, Count = 5 }
```